# Help me to determine: Does this laptop have wireless?

Tags: wireless, drivers, hardware, intel

I've got a pair of HP-Compaq nc8000s and it seems they *should* have wireless... but when I check networkmanager I don't see it, nor when I check in all the normal places.

From this lshw output: http://pastebin.com/SwZeTDEx I get the impression there is no wireless adapter - even though the systems both have wireless lights and buttons and even report that the wireless is on in the BIOS!

Am I missing something?

### Update:

Having a look at the manual, it seems that this model does in fact have wireless (it has all the physical signs of it as well, including the antennae!), but it seems from a forum thread I read (sorry don't have the link to hand) that these systems stopped working with Ubuntu (in terms of wireless) in 8.10 and up :(.

The search continues afresh.

Comment: Can you check if there are any restricted / proprietary wireless drivers that are available? That usually does the trick for me. I am guessing you know where to look for them. But then again, you need to have a working internet to download the driver... :P

Comment: @jokerdino that's the other strange thing, there are none that show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lshw command output suggests that there is no wireless card installed....

I checked the spec for HP-Compaq nc8000s...and there Wireless Card is optional...so in my opinion your laptop does NOT have wireless

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping beyond hope that these might have it (I mean, why include a button to enable something that's not even there!). I will probably have to open one of them and check physically :P...

Or buy a wireless adapter for each one (so I can give them away later).

Comment: We've since looked at the manual and it seems that this model does have wireless - so the search begins again. It also seems that these models worked with Ubuntu 8.04 just fine in terms of wireless - and then stopped working so fine in 8.10 and up according to a forum thread I read. Gonna have to keep digging on this one. Thanks for the help though. I'm going to keep looking for a solution.